# How to conduct a pairwise fisher exact test?

Tags: r

I am trying to do a `pairwise.fisher.exact` test, but I have some problems with it. Unfortunately, I can't find any solutions on the internet. Thus, I hope that someone can help me. 
This is my data:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(yes = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 4L, 7L, 
4L, 1L, 6L, 25L, 29L, 66L, 18L, 77L, 53L, 19L, 13L, 15L, 7L, 
20L, 58L, 34L, 38L, 39L, 11L, 45L, 33L, 50L, 48L, 42L, 29L), 
    no = c(898L, 1438L, 1435L, 1435L, 1439L, 1440L, 1440L, 1428L, 
    1436L, 1433L, 1436L, 1439L, 1434L, 1415L, 1351L, 1374L, 1422L, 
    1363L, 1387L, 1421L, 1427L, 1425L, 1433L, 1420L, 1382L, 1406L, 
    1402L, 1401L, 1429L, 1395L, 1407L, 1390L, 1392L, 1398L, 907L
    ), sum = c(900L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 
    1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1380L, 1440L, 
    1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 
    1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 1440L, 
    936L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))
```

At first, I did a `fisher.test` to see whether there is a difference between "yes" and "no". `fisher.test(test,simulate.p.value=TRUE)` R gives me a significant difference, so that I want to know between which "yes" and "no" is the difference. I wrote:

```
pairwise.fisher.test(c(2,2,5,5,1,0,0,12,4,7,4,1,6,25,29,66,18,77,53,19,13,15,7,20,58,34,38,39,11,45,33,50,48,42,29),c(900,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,936),p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

R shows me the difference between the "yes" and "no", but just for the first 30 values. It says:

> "reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5 rows"

Thus, the last 5 rows are not showing anymore. I don't know, how to solve this problem.

Comment: Which package is the `pairwise.fisher.test` function you are using from?

Comment: It is the library(fmsb)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with the pairwise Fisher exact test.. but the problem you report at the end of your post, it not really a problem: it just means that R is limiting the output of `pairwise.fisher.test`. If you really want to see the whole output, just assign the returned value of `pairwise.fisher.test` to a variable (`result <- pairwise.fisher.test(c(2,...))`), let's say `result`, and then do `View(result)` or `View(result[["p.value"]]).`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know how to see the whole output. Now it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

result <- pairwise.fisher.test(c(2,2,5,5,1,0,0,12,4,7,4,1,6,25,29,66,18,77,53,19,13,15,7,20,58,34,38,39,11,45,33,50,48,42,29), c(900,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1440,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,1400,936),p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")

View(result[["p.value"]])